# How to play next song in the playlist automatically if no key is pressed by the user?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to give the option to the user to play, pause, play next or previous song. If the user does not press anything, the next song in the list should be played automatically. Currently the program halts for the input from the user.

I have tried playing the song in another thread and wait for the user to enter the choice in main thread. But the problem is that main thread waits for the input from the user before playing the next song.

```
def music(file):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    try:
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(0)
    except:
        pass

def pause():
    print(file + " paused")
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    global set
    set = 1

def playsong():
    global set
    global t1
    print ("Playing song named : " + file)
    if file != "" and set==0:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = music ,args=(file,))
        t1.setName("audio bajao")
        t1.start()
ch = 1
song_list = ["song1.mp3","song2.mp3"]
while((i < len(song_list)) and (ch != 5) ):
    ch = input("Enter choice ")
    file = song_list[i]
    if(ch == 1):
        playsong()
    elif(ch == 2):
        ch = 1
        pause()
    elif(ch == 3):
        #play previous song
        ch = 1
        i -= 2
    elif (ch == 4):
        #play next song
        ch = 1
    elif (ch == 5):
        break
    i += 1
```

I want the program should play the next song from the list when the song ends if no key is pressed by the user. It should not ask the user again to press the play key to play the next song.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `pygame.mixer.get_busy()`

To implement this, add some kind of timer variable, I personally prefer tick counters, So...

```
inactive_ticks = 0
```

After that, in your main event loop, use `pygame.mixer.get_busy()` to check if there is music being played or not, then...

```
if not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    inactive_ticks += 1

    if inactive_ticks == 100:
        # Play the next song
        inactive_ticks = 0
```

That should work.